# why do battery leaks still happen

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Battery leaks was an issue in the 80s and 90s, and since quality and innovation is constantly improving, I thought battery leak might be slowly going away. But I found that even nowadays, name brand alkaline batteries still leak after a while, even if originally concealed in a tight package of the metal shell. Is it true that the chemical in an alkaline battery inherently expands in volume over time, and make the alkaline battery leak issue unavoidable?

also why does the alkaline expand in volume over time?